# Synergy Client Mouse Speed (Slow)

Tags: linux, windows-xp, mouse, synergy

I'm using synergy+ with Windows XP as a server and a CentOS client. The mouse speed on the client (Linux) seems really slow. Is there a way to have the mouse speed from the server persist to the clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem and I updated from from synergy to synergy+ and now the speed is very fast.

Comment: I did the same thing but forgot to come back and update this post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turn off mouse trails and pointer shadowing in the mouse options on the Windows computer.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to figure this issue out?  I just reinstalled and am having these issues.  I found that it was improved after activating my graphics drivers but still miserable.

I have a very similar set up, running Windows 7 (server) and Ubuntu 9.10 (client).

On my client machine I have installed Synergy and Synergy+ and configured my box to automatically run Synergy when the computer starts.  There are suggested configurations.  I have tried both.

Both configurations are found below, but they don't work for me.

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynergyHowto
- http://www.teknynja.com/2008/04/ubuntu-804-hardy-heron-synergy-client.html

Comment: Nope I never did find a solution. :(

Comment: See accepted answer, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I occasionally get the slow mouse problem with Synergy+. My setup is Windows 7 as the server and Snow Leopard as the client.

When this happens, I disable/disconnect the WiFi on the server and the mouse speed is back to normal.